# Check if nullable boolean has value and if all are equal from list

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a nullable boolean property of an object inside a list, I want to check if all are equal and return its value, and return null if there is a value that is not equal.

e.g.

```
Object1
    string Name
    bool? NullBool
```

Object1 is in list e.g. `List<Object1>` and I just need to check and return `NullBool` using Linq

I want to do something like

```
bool? returnVal = <my Linq / Function to get what I want>
```

Comment: Check that all of what are equal? That all of the boolean values are equal?

Comment: yes, and I just want to return a nullable boolean, not a list of nullable boolean..

Comment: Get the distinct for NullBool, if all are same you should get only one record :)

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty, but:

```
IEnumerable<Object1> objects = ...

var firstTwoDistinctValues = objects.Select(o => o.NullBool)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .Take(2) // Early exit
                                    .ToList();

var result = firstTwoDistinctValues.Count == 2
             ? null : firstTwoDistinctValues.SingleOrDefault();
```

Now that's pretty efficient because:

- It works without enumerating the source-collection more than once. This isn't such a big deal when the source is a list, but could be important if the source is an expensive / non-deterministic query.
- It exits early  if there's more than unique value.

Additionally, it will work fine when the source-collection is empty.

For a  list, you can also efficiently do:

```
IList<Object1> objects = ...

var firstNullBool = objects.Select(o => o.NullBool).FirstOrDefault();
var result = objects.All(o => o.NullBool == firstNullBool) ? firstNullBool : null;
```

Comment: @rob: It's an optimization - exit early if more than one distinct value is found - the result is definitely going to be null, so no point enumerating further.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = list.Select(elem => elem.NullBool).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 .Aggregate((acc, elem) => acc == elem ? acc : null);
```

Comment: +1: Very elegant. I would handle the empty sequence better though. Also, it's a pity we can't get early exit with `Aggregate`.

Comment: @Ani, Good suggestion--added an empty list check. Shame I can't think of anything slicker than `?:` for it...

Comment: I would do: `list.Select(elem => elem.NullBool).DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate((acc, elem) => acc == elem ? acc : null)`

Comment: @Ani--fantastically clean query! I've incorporated it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking someting in the lines of this?

```
public static bool? CheckIfAllAreTheSame(List<Object1> bools)
{
    if (bools.All(b => b.NullBool == true))
        return true; // ... they are all true;
    if (bools.All(b => b.NullBool == false))
        return false;// ... they are all false
    return null;// ... they are not all the same...
}
```

Comment: ahhh yes, I think this is what I need. check back with you later.

Comment: And just to have mentioned it: this will return `true` if the list is empty, so if that's not desired behavior you need to modify the function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thing = (from x in objects where (x.NullBool.HasValue 
   && x.NullBool.Value == whatever) select x).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: whatever you want to compare against ( eg, true or false ), -- eg get every nullable bool that is true,